# <base> and linking to an ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This rather a weird problem.

I have set a `<base href="<?php echo $domainName; ?>/">`

`<?php echo $domainName; ?>` = the domain directory, so all links will start with www.domainname.com/

I am now trying to set a scroll-up button, so I have a div with and ID `id="project-showcase"` and the button links to that section `href="#project-showcase"`.

Well, the problem is it keep on going back to the home page when clicked on the button and it searches for #project-showcase there! I found out that the problem is because of the `<base>...`

I need the base to be there, but have no clue how to make it not to be applied to this specific button! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to change the `href`s slightly as follows:

```
href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>#YOUR_DIV_ID"
```